# How do I access a model object in a view using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm just new with asp.net mvc using razor syntax in the view and I would like to know how can I use a model object inside a jQuery routine to set an img src?

For ex:

```
 setSourceImage()
    {
       @foreach(var myPaths in Model)
       {
        @: jQuery('#sampleImage').attr('src',myPaths.imgPath)
       }
    }
```

I know the syntax is wrong, but in a sense that is what I want to achieve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the syntax is wrong. I would recommend you using the `Json.Encode` method to safely serialize the property of your model you are interested in:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setSourceImage() {
        var imageSources = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Select(x => x.imgPath)));
        for (var i = 0; i < imageSources.length; i++) {
            jQuery('#sampleImage').attr('src', imageSources[i])
        }
    }
</script>
```

which might be rendered as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setSourceImage() {
        var imageSources = ['/images/img1.jpg', '/images/img2.jpg'];
        for (var i = 0; i < imageSources.length; i++) {
            jQuery('#sampleImage').attr('src', imageSources[i])
        }
    }
</script>
```

Obviously for this to work the `imgPath` property of your model should contain an absolute or relative url to the image on the server. It should not contain the physical location of the image like `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\images\img1.jpg`. If this is the case you will have to transform this property on the server before rendering the view.

Comment: Hello, I tried to follow your suggestion but I get this error: highlighted is the code....var imageSources = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Select(x => x.Modelnumber)));.....The error says: An error occured during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately: Compiler Error Message: CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.

Comment: Is your view strongly typed? You must have a model: `@model SomeType` at the top.

Comment: Most probably that's my issue, it's not strongly type when I created my view. I'll try it later...thanks